# Simple localization issue with cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, localization

I have a table with two fields, name and name_spa

To retrieve the correct language, I have to do something like this in the view:

```
if($locale=='eng'){
  echo $var['Model']['name'];
}else{
  echo $var['Model']['name_spa'];
}
```

However, Id like to do something like this:

```
echo $var['Model']['lname'][$locale];
```

I tried using virtual fields but this didnt work. I didn't use i18n because it was way too complex for what I needed.

```
public $virtualFields = array($lname => array(
                    'enh' => $this->name,
                    'spa' => $this->name_spa,
                ));
```

Comment: You're going drastically wrong by wanting to put your logic in the View. That's not MVC at all. The logic goes in the controller, and this locale check is no different. Set one variable in your controller and call that from your view. Furthermore, how do you specify your $locale variable?

Comment: in AppController, beforeRender
`$this->set('locale', Configure::read('Config.language'));`

Answer (score 0):

Your virtualFields array seems invalid to me. As others mentioned, you should not be performing these things inside your view. One option might be to construct the virtualFields array just before the find(), something like:

Inside your model:

```
Public function findLocalized($id, $locale) {
     if ('spa' === $locale) {
         $this->virtualFields['name_localized'] = 'name_spa';
     } else {
        $this->virtualFields['name_localized'] = 'name';
     }

     return $this->find('first', array(
          'conditions' => array('id' => $id)
     ));
}
```

In your controller, use:

```
$this->set('var', $this->MyModel->findLocalized($id, $locale));
```

And use in view:

```
echo $var['Model']['name_localized'];
```

Which will outout the name in the requested $locale.

Still, you'd better rethink your strategy for localization